# Is model.publish event occur only during Revit publish action?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management, autodesk-bim360, autodesk-webhooks

Description of this event says: "*When a Revit Cloud Worksharing model is queued or when processing starts.*"

Does it mean that this event occurs only after a model was published from Revit? Or it includes other cases (e.g. when we transfer the Revit Cloud Worksharing model through Autodesk Desktop Connector to BIM360 project?)

Thank you

Comment: Jack, I think it should be also included, but it looks not working with my test. Please bear with me checking with engineer team.

Comment: @XiaodongLiang Thank you. I look forward to more information

Comment: sorry for letting you wait.  I am told if what you meant 'transfer the RCW file through Autodesk Deskop Connector' is 'put a file to local work sharing folder, then sync to BIM360 folder by Desktop Connector', then yes, the event model.publish is not triggered because it is not a  cloud model. model.publish” event is specific to RCM/RCW-based cloud models, and only raised when the model is published from RCM Services to BIM 360 Docs.

Comment: If what your scenario is is different, could you share more information? a test video may be more helpful. thank you

Comment: @XiaodongLiang This was exactly my scenario. Thank you) Your information is very helpful~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@XiaodongLiang answered my question in comments:

> I am told if what you meant 'transfer the RCW file through Autodesk
>   Deskop Connector' is 'put a file to local work sharing folder, then
>   sync to BIM360 folder by Desktop Connector', then yes, the event
>   model.publish is not triggered because it is not a cloud model.
>   model.publish” event is specific to RCM/RCW-based cloud models, and
>   only raised when the model is published from RCM Services to BIM 360
>   Docs